# Can we define the Schema Model dynamically in the kendo ui

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using KendoUi controls. I have defined the dataSource like

```
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   schema: {
    model: {
       id: "ProductID",
         fields: {
            ProductID: { type:"id" },
            ProductName: {type:"string"}
           }      
         }
       }          
     });
```

Now my question is can we define `fileds` as an `array` like

```
 var arry = [{ProductID:{type:"id"}}, {ProductName:{type:"string"}}];
```

Now can we define the dataSource like

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   schema: {
    model: {
       id: "ProductID",
         fields: arry
         }
       }          
     });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both definitions are not equivalent.

The first one:

```
fields: { 
    ProductID: { type:"id" },
    ProductName: {type:"string"}
}
```

uses associate arrays (index are `ProductID` and `ProductName`) while the second:

```
var arry = [{ProductID:{type:"id"}}, {ProductName:{type:"string"}}];
...
fields: arry
...
```

You use an array with index `0` and `1`.

You can define them dynamically but you should define `arry` as:

```
var arry = { ProductID:{type:"id"}, ProductName:{type:"string"} };
```

or

```
var arry = {};
arry.ProductID = { type: "id" };
arry.ProductName = { type : "string" };
```

or

```
var arry = {};
arry["ProductID"] = { type: "id" };
arry["ProductName"] = { type : "string" };
```

but `arr` needs to be an `object` and not an `array`